# How to extend the color palette in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I coded the following function:

```
def plot_cumulative_dynamic_auc(risk_score, label, color=None):

    auc, mean_auc = cumulative_dynamic_auc(y_trn, y_test, risk_score, times)
    plt.plot(times, auc, marker="o", color=color, label=label)
    plt.xlabel("days from enrollment")
    plt.ylabel("time-dependent AUC")
    plt.axhline(mean_auc, color=color, linestyle="--")
    plt.legend()
```

And then the for-loop:

```
for i, col in enumerate(num_columns):
    plot_cumulative_dynamic_auc(X_test.iloc[:, i], col, color="C{}".format(i))
    ret = concordance_index_ipcw(y_trn, y_test, X_test.iloc[:, i], tau=times[-1])
```

As the for loop iterates over num_columns which has 40 variables, the standard palette only offers 10 colors. However, I want to have every variable its own color. Is there a way to code it also being flexible when it comes to the number of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib offers `tab20`, which is too restrictive for your case. Since you have a lot of lines, a possible solution is to use a colormap, or more than one. Take a look at the [available color maps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

#### A single colormap

By choosing an appropriate colormap, we will have a decent capability to understand the plot. For example, using `hsv`:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

N = 40 # number of lines
x = np.array([0, 1])
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, N)

discr = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
# create N colors from the colormap
colors = cm.hsv(discr)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, t in enumerate(theta):
    ax.plot(x, np.tan(t) * x, color=colors[i])
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

As you can see, the first and last lines uses similar colors, so if the colormap is cyclic (such as `hsv`) it might be a good idea to restrict the discretization range, for example `discr = np.linspace(0, 0.75, N)`.

#### Creating colors from multiple colormaps

Matplotlib offers many diverging colormaps. We can use them to create a combination of colors, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# compile a list of colormaps
colormaps = [cm.Reds_r, cm.Blues_r, cm.Greens_r, cm.Purples_r]
N = 40 # number of lines
x = np.array([0, 1])
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, N)

# extract the following number of colors for each colormap
n_cols_per_cm = int(np.ceil(N / len(colormaps)))
# discretize the colormap. Note the upper limit of 0.75, so we
# avoid too white-ish colors
discr = np.linspace(0, 0.75, n_cols_per_cm)

# extract the colors
colors = np.zeros((n_cols_per_cm * len(colormaps), 4))
for i, cmap in enumerate(colormaps):
    colors[i * n_cols_per_cm : (i + 1) * n_cols_per_cm, :] = cmap(discr)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, t in enumerate(theta):
    ax.plot(x, np.tan(t) * x, color=colors[i])
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]